# How can I multiply an array elements between another array?

Tags: javascript

I want to do it with the forEach loop but I can't do it, what I want to do is the following

For example i have the first array:

```
let numbersA = [4,5,6,7,8];
```

Then i have the last array:

```
let numbersB = [2,3,4,5,6];
```

The expected output:

> 4 * 2 = 8

> 4*3 = 12

> 4 * 4 = 16

> 4 * 5 = 20

> 4 * 6 = 24

and now comes the second multiplication of the first array of the second number:

> 5 * 2 = 10

> 5 * 3 = 15

> 5 * 4 = 20

> 5 * 5 = 25

> 5 * 6 = 30

How can I get this result, I want to do it with the forEach loop, using arrow functions but I got stuck

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I got stuck with forEach loop because I don't know if I have to do a loop or two to do the multiplications @TusharShahi

Comment: It might look like bad code, but just use two nested `for` loops. You can do the exact same thing with `.forEach()` too, but that can cause problems in some rare senarios. 
If you absolutely need to use `.forEach()`, then try `array1.forEach(item1 => array2.forEach(item2 => doSomething(item1 * item2)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** to print out the equation:

```js
let numbersA = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let numbersB = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
numbersA.forEach(a => {
    numbersB.forEach(b => console.log(`${a} * ${b} = ${a * b}`));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let numbersA = [4,5,6,7,8];
let numbersB = [2,3,4,5,6];
numbersA.forEach(a => numbersB.forEach(b => console.log(a * b)));
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation. It would be very helpful for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this using nested `forEach`:

```
numbersA.forEach((itemA) => {
   numbersB.forEach((itemB) => {
       console.log(itemA * itemB);
   });
});
```